# Как проверить атрибут списка jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

Есть два списка и кнопка. Как правильно написать условия, что если второй список имеет свойство `disabled`, тогда и кнопке тоже нужно присвоить `disabled`?

Как присвоить кнопки аттрибут, разобрался. Это так:

```
$('#btn').attr('disabled', true);
```

А как получить свойство и проверить списка?

Comment: В вашем вопросе недостаточно данных для ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получить значение атрибута

```
var is_disabled = $('#btn').attr('disabled');
```

Comment: Вывожу через Alert возвращает undefinded

Comment: если атрибут не указан в тегах явно, то всё нормально, так и должно быть

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn').prop('disabled', true); // записать
$('#btn').prop('disabled'); // прочитать
```